# Is it possible to read Excel file from Apache Zeppellin to PySpark or to a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera

I have got a file in HDFS (/user/username/Project/data/file.xlsx) that I want to read into a DataFrame. (I do not care if it is a PySpark DataFrame or Pandas, but Pandas is preferred.)

I am using a Zeppelin Notebook to do my code.

Is it possible to get data from this file?

I have already tried the following commands, but none of them worked:

- `df = pd.read_excel("/user/username/Project/data/file.xlsx")`
- `df = pd.read_excel("hdfs:///user/username/Project/data/file.xlsx")`
- `df = pd.read_excel("hdfs://user/username/Project/data/file.xlsx")`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can read files stored in hdfs directly with pandas.

You probably have to either :

- load the file into spark then use toPandas()

  df = spark.read.format("excel").load("hdfs:xxx").toPandas()
- use some alternative to enable pandas to read directly, as described [here](https://creativedata.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SAP/pages/61177860/Python+-+Read+Write+files+from+HDFS)

Answer (score 0):

It seems export and import commands in Python Interpreter in Apache Zeppellin can be only realised through "pd.read_csv" and "to_csv" modules.